# Clear serial port receive buffer in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

Just want to know how do we clear the receive buffer of my serial port in C#. Seems like the data in the receive buffer just keep accumulating. 
For example, the flow of incoming data is: [Data A], [Data B], [Data C]. The data I want is just [Data C].
I'm thinking of doing like, when I receive [Data A] and [Data B], I do a clear buffer. Only when [Data C] is received, I continue process. Is this the way to do it in C#?

Comment: How are you using the serial port? Are you using `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` then you could use the two methods:

`DiscardInBuffer()` and `DiscardOutBuffer()` to flush the buffers.

If you are reading the data from a serial port:

```
private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Open) return; // We can't receive data if the port has already been closed.  This prevents IO Errors from being half way through receiving data when the port is closed.
    string line = String.empty;
    try
    {
        line = _SerialPort.ReadLine();
        line = line.Trim();
       //process your data if it is "DATA C", otherwise ignore
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        //process any errors
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. My transmitter will always transmit data. Is just that the receiver which is my C# program is not always receiving the data to process. If I did not process the data, the receive buffer will accumulate the data right? Then is it that I will have to always do DiscardInBuffer() when I'm not processing the receive data?

Comment: @maniac84 Yes this should be fine. Alternatively you could read the buffer, and in your application logic, simply ignore the data received. Is there always a similar termination character? See my edit.

Answer (score 15):

Use `port.DiscardOutBuffer(); and port.DiscardInBuffer();` to clear the serial port buffers

Comment: For those who uses CP21xx UART-to-USB transceiver, please note that since late 2022, the CP21xx chip will effectively ignore Discard Buffer commands and you now have to manually read the data from the serial port. See [this](https://siliconlabs.my.site.com/community/s/question/0D58Y00009qlfyBSAQ/version-1120167-of-the-cp2105-driver-ignores-the-net-serial-port-class-discardinbuffer-method-version-1100509-works-correctly?language=es_MX)

Answer (score 7):

There are two buffers. One buffer is associated with the serial port and the other with its base stream, where data from the port buffer is streamed into.  DiscardIn Buffer() just gets data from the Serial Port buffer discarded.  There is still data in the Base Stream that you will read.  So, besides using DiscardInBuffer, also use SP.BaseStream.Flush().  Now you have a clean slate!  If you are not getting a lot of data, simply get rid of the base stream: SP.BaseStream.Dispose().

Since you are still getting the data received event, yo can read it and not put yourself in jeopardy of losing data.

Answer (score 6):

you can use like

```
port.DiscardOutBuffer();
port.DiscardInBuffer();
port.Close();
port.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(onDataReceived);
port = null;
```