# Add message to ignore list if this message was repeated

Tags: c#, serial-port, filtering

Maybe someone can provide the best way how to ignore the message if this message was repeated, what I should use for ignoring, save messages in list and iterate through list or save all messages to the file, what is the best way? I'm reading data from serial port using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace canSniff
    {
    class PortDataReceived
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new  SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            mySerialPort.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                            object sender,
                            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
            Console.Write(indata);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To ignore the previous message, clear the buffer: `mySerialPort.DiscardInBuffer()` 

For more information, look at the answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571522/clear-serial-port-receive-buffer-in-c-sharp

Comment: I need to ignore for 5 mnutes for example, when all standart messages will be ignored, i will press the button and new code will arrive, this button code i should handle

Comment: Can you tell me please, this will works like this: All recieved messages i will store to the buffer and if  one of 100 differrent messages will arrive again and reach the same message in buffer this message will be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `HashSet<string>` to store the received messages.
If you should save it as file, depends on how the application is used. The code below knows as long the application is running about received messages.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace canSniff
    {
    class PortDataReceived
    {

        private HashSet<string> _messages = new HashSet<string>();

        public static void Main()
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new  SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            mySerialPort.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                            object sender,
                            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

            if(_messages.Add(indata))
            {
                 // the message was added 
                 Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
                 Console.Write(indata);
            }
            else
            {
                  // do something with the omitted message that was allready in the list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will learn a little bit about HashSet<String>. U are right the messages should be ignored once, when application is running

Comment: If this is the answer that you expect you can upvote and accept it as answer. Thank you.