# how to clear data bytes from serial port Communication in c#

Tags: c#

i have problem, i receive message from serial port and how to clear data bytes from serial port in c#, i try this SerialPort1.Clear(); but not work.

```
while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 112)
               {
                    SerialPort1.Clear();
                }
```

Comment: C# is case-sensitive. Did you mean `serialPort1.Clear()`?

Comment: yes how to bytes from serialport, "SerialPort.Clear()" just ilustration my logic. not realy work..

Comment: In that case you're probably looking for this: [Clear serial port receive buffer in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571522/clear-serial-port-receive-buffer-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Hard to guess why you are not using SerialPort.DiscardInBuffer().  Well, other than that it almost never does what you want it to do since it is completely unpredictable what you throw away.

Answer (score 1):

Reading all bytes might solve the problem.

```
int readCount = serialPort.BytesToRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[readCount];
serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, readCount);
```

I hope this would be helpful.